# SQL Command Search For Single Word vs. Two

Tags: sql, joomla, spam

I'm trying to clean up a Joomla DB that's been left un updated (clients love em hate em) for years. I'm going to migrate the data to a 3.0 version but before I do that I'd like to clean it up as best I can.

Any way... I'm trying to figure out the correct SQL command to select (I will delete later) a column called "name" in the jos_users table. It looks like most of the malicious bots that visited the site entered a name with one word vs what a real users does which is to enter a first and last name.

I've used this command with no joy.

```
select from jos_users where not (instr(name, ' '))
```

Now I was told to use quotes but that too does not work.

```
select from jos_users where not (instr(name, " "))
```

I've used every conceivable variation of this and looked for a solution on Google with no success.

Any help would be super helpful.

One a side note I got this command from a fantastic article that dives into Joomla and how to clean up spam accounts. You can find it below.

http://www.cyprich.com/2010/11/12/how-to-delete-spam-accounts-in-joomla/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly your requirement is to find names with no whitespaces, so:

```
SELECT * FROM jos_users WHERE name NOT LIKE '% %';
```

Comment: For any one Following this question the following selects only .com emails.  I have found that most of the bogus users came from .com  The following command finds it.  SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE name NOT LIKE '% %' 
  AND email NOT LIKE '%.edu';